# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Paste'_worksheet' Faild

Tags: vba

This was working fine, only sometimes I get this error, but it is happening more and more. Like it will work one a group of invoices, I will try it agian and it works on like half of them the next time. It is breaking at the .Paste Just cant firgure out what it is. I am converting PDF to Excel. This method has given me the best results so for and all my other code that works from the output is already writtten

```
Sub PDF_To_Excel()


Dim automate_sh As Worksheet
Set automate_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automate")

Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = automate_sh.Range("E11").Value
excel_path = automate_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)

Dim wa As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim wr As Object

Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")

wa.Visible = True

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet




For Each f In fo.Files
Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")

Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
wr.WholeStory



Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
wr.Copy


nsh.Paste

nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))


doc.Close False
nwb.Close False
Next

wa.Quit



MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run-time+error+1004

Comment: @KenWhite There is a lot of info on just the Application or Object Run time Error 1004 but not on the Paste Method. Actually only found 3 and two were not ever answered and the other one did have a fix that did not work for me did cut down on the number of times the error pops up. I did add `DoEvents` and `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))` . It does cut down on the number of times it gets the error but didnt really solve my issue